# Xamarin Forms editor text not showing correctly on android

Tags: android, xamarin, editor

I have this page in an app, where I need some Editor components to be placed in an specific place and with an specific place. When I set a small HeightRequest, however, the editors don't show the text correctly on android.

I tried adjusting the FontSize and the Margin to show it correctly, but none of them seems to have any effect.

Here are the screens from both iOS: [image: iOS] and Android: [image: Android].

What should I do to have the desired effect on Android as well?

EDIT:

I'm talking about the part where it says "Formação Acadêmica"
I set the HeightRequest, but I imagine since it is a small HeightRequest, the text gets cut off in android.

here's the code that creates that part:

```
            Editor editor = new Editor();
            if (atributo.tipo.Equals(Atributo.NUMERICO) || atributo.tipo.Equals(Atributo.INTEGER)) {
                editor.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            }

            if (atributoDoc.valor != null) {
                editor.Text = atributoDoc.valor;
            }

            //(...)

            editor.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty, "IsEnabled");
            editor.BindingContext = container;
            editor.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(1, 1, 0, 0.4);
            editor.WidthRequest = atributoDoc.largura * ratio;
            editor.HeightRequest = atributoDoc.altura * ratio;
            editor.FontSize = editor.FontSize * ratio;

            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.AnchorX = frame.AnchorY = 0;
            frame.OutlineColor = Color.Black;
            frame.Padding = 0;
            frame.Content = editor;
            frame.HasShadow = false;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                container.Children.Add(frame, Constraint.Constant(atributoDoc.posicaoX * ratio), Constraint.Constant(atributoDoc.posicaoY * ratio + contImage.Y));
            });
```

Comment: Are you taking about the third part of your page? Can you please post your code?

Comment: Edited with some code and clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You have to write customerederer and

```
 protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    // Change the text on custompropertychange
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    Control.SetText("CustomText", TextView.BufferType.Spannable);     
    }
```